# Are browsers vulnerable to Authorization Code Interception Attacks?

Tags: web-browser, oauth2

[RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) states "The operating systems must allow a custom URI scheme to be registered by multiple applications." Are web apps vulnerable to this attack? Could a web app link open a malicious app via a custom URI scheme?

Comment: It's an RFC, not necessarily a vulnerability? It requires A. an application and it's uri handler to be installed on the victim site and B. the user visiting a webpage hosting a URI with said protocol. It could probably be used for persistence in combination with a JS injector or something but I don't think this is a vulnerability per se?

Comment: Can you re-phrase the question to connect some dots? It's not clear how all the things you bring up relate.